# Как скачать видео больше 20мб которое отправил пользователь aiogram

Tags: telegram-bot, aiogram, видео, pyrogram

Нужно скачивать видео на сервер которое отправляет пользователь бота, но tg bot api дает скачивать максимум 20мб,как я понял для этого нужно использовать tg api а не tg bot api,с помощью какой библиотеки лучше всего скачивать видео которое весит больше чем 20 мб и как это сделать?